# How do you integrate Shopify ONLY for checkout and payment?

Tags: shopify

I'm currently building a client site in Craft CMS and they'd like to be able to sell items through the website. It's been suggested that we 'integrate' shopify with the site for selling, so I've set up a trial store.

The problem is that when I set up a custom domain for my Shopify store (changing the CNAME record with the site host), visiting the domain shows me the root of the shopify store, and not the website I'm currently developing. Shopify keep saying it 'integrates' with existing websites but how do you achieve this?

**Goal: To use a website designed, built and managed inside Craft CMS, then use Shopify ONLY for the Cart & checkout process. The domain should always be the custom domain and not the mydomain.shopify.com one.**

Am I missing something simple, or is it mis-advertised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will still want to host your Craft site on your main domain, and then setup a subdomain to point to the Shopify site. Then handle all the product display on your Craft site, and use [this plugin](https://github.com/davist11/craft-shopify) to link up the Shopify products to the Craft products. Finally, all you have to do is add the [add to cart forms](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/cart-page/adding-to-the-cart-from-a-remote-website), and then let Shopify handle the cart and checkout process.

Comment: Ah I understand! Hadn't thought of using a subdomain. I had everything else nailed except the domain issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Shopify's checkout and payment processing into an existing website, you can follow these steps:

Create a Shopify store if you don't already have one.
Navigate to the "Checkout" section in the Shopify admin and select "Checkout settings."
Enable the "Customer billing and shipping information" option to allow customers to enter their billing and shipping information during checkout.
Select "Shopify Payments" or another payment gateway as the payment method.
Generate a checkout API key from the "Checkout" section of the Shopify admin.
Integrate the Shopify checkout into your website using the API key and the Shopify Checkout API.
Add the necessary product and checkout buttons to your website, and ensure that the correct product and pricing information is passed to the Shopify checkout.
Test the integration thoroughly to ensure it is working correctly.